# How to write an actionable sentence in the Dutch language?

Tags: grammar, writing, dutch

I'm trying to improve my GTD system and a recurring suggested theme is to make your goals actionable. Things like "Repair laptop, cleanup kitchen, buy milk, call mother' all start with the verb in front. This helps making your tasks goal-oriented.

As my natural language is Dutch, it's easier to write Dutch. The Dutch language, however, has a different buildup than the English language. In Dutch the noun is often placed in front. Those same tasks would be "Laptop repareren, keuken opruimen, melk kopen, moeder opbellen'.

What is the best way to write Dutch tasks in a short and more actionable manner?

Comment: Maybe you want to look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood.

Comment: Repareer de laptop, ruim de keuken op, koop melk, etc.  Notice in English we can also say "clean the kitchen up", however, in English "clean up the kitchen" is also acceptable. If you replace "the kitchen" with a pronoun, though, "up" needs to return to its 'natural' position. E.g. "clean it up".

Comment: I do not see how object+verb is less actionable than verb+object.